# Maven plugin for Spring-boot cannot support multiple arguments?

Tags: maven-plugin, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot version `1.0.1.RELEASE`. I tried to run `mvn spring-boot:run` with arguments.

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/ on "Configuration Section" I should use `-Drun.arguments` without telling me any example for multiple inline arguments. So, I tried to call `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=8181 --debug --spring.thymeleaf.cache=false"` but sadly it failed.

It seems that it can only support one argument, e.g. `-Drun.arguments="--debug"`

What's the correct one? Does it support multiple arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comma-separated (it's Maven doing the conversion not Spring).